# Get integer from GTKEntry in new window

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I need a function 
`int askInteger(...);` called via a button.

which open a dialog with a `GTKEntry`, and returns the integer from the entry form.

Then I can use this integer.

The problem is that I tried using GTK Message Dialog, but it doesn't work because `gtk_container_add` doesn't work as `GTKMessageDialog` can take only one widget (itself).

How can I work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GtkDialog` (`gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons (..)` in combination with a `GtkGrid` and place `your_widget`s in the grid, add the `grid` to the `dialog`.

[Assuming you are using `gtk+ 3.x`, if `gtk+ 2.x`, use `GtkTable` instead]